# rvm-shell command stops executing other commands

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have written a shell script where i wrote one rvm-shell command. The issue is any line after this command will not get executed. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set x
rvm-shell ruby-1.9.3-p448@global //after this line not anything get executed
echo $?  //not get executed
clear    //not get executed

rails s  //not get executed which i want to run
```

Comment: accept the solution if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

```
rvm-shell ruby-1.9.3-p448@global
```

without any parameters is equivalent to running

```
rvm ruby-1.9.3-p448@global do bash
```

which will enter shell session and wait for your input.

what you need is:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448@global
```

or:

```
source "$( rvm ruby-1.9.3-p448@global do rvm env --path )"
```

debugging `source`:

```
env_file="$( rvm ruby-1.9.3-p448@global do rvm env --path )"
echo "env_file:$env_file:"
source "$env_file"
```

or use this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rvm-shell ruby-1.9.3-p448@global

rails s
```

Comment: i really tried lot of times this source command but it do not work in my case. in any case in script i did get an answer and that is 'rvm use ...' will not work. that is why i tried to use rvm-shell command by this the rvm is get selected but the next commands will not get executed

Comment: i seen in rvm-shell script the last line was exec ${selected_shell} "$@" . what is the meaning of this line.because after this line not a single command get executed from my script

Comment: added debugging, what do you see in `env_file`? what version of rvm is this?

Comment: the first env_file output is env_file:/home/pragmatic/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global:  and next script output is /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory

Comment: yes sir thanks for help now a added rails s after a source "$env_file" line and the rails server gets started. thank i was looking for this for last 2 days. can you please explain a little more on this script. just a few lines.thanks in advance

Comment: for every ruby/gemset rvm keeps an environment file, the first command finds it, then it's enough to `source` it to load proper ruby